# How do I stop my Excel spreadsheets from opening when starting my IMac and also the first time I open Excel?

Tags: imac

When I first turn on my IMac each day, it opens all of my Excel spreadsheets, including ones that were not used previously.  (Using Microsoft Office Mac 2011)  When it gets to one that is passworded, it will stop and ask for the password and also give me a cancel option.  When I cancel, I get the message "Would you like to cancel opening all files at your XLStart location? (Macintosh HD:Users:starsinc:Documents:Excel Docs)?". This also happens the first time I open my excel program each day.  I unchecked "Close windows when quitting an application" under General in System Preferences but that did not solve it.  I have been unsuccessful in trying to locate where to change this at.  Help!!

Answer (score 1):

One idea: try right-clicking (or hold the ctrl key and click) the Excel icon on your Dock, and see if *Options > Open at Login* is ticked.  If it is ticked, click that menu entry to untick it.